# Sending image file name to .TXT in VB gives error

Tags: vb.net

Using the Code bellow I'm trying to make a compiler that sends image names to a .TXT file, that can then be later read by another program to make a overworld map (like in the old NES Zelda games).The problem is on line 16 (15 if you don't count spaces) there's a problem when the program gets to that bit which is sending the image name it returns this error:

"Operator '&' is not defined for string "Me.BackgroundImage = WindowsAppl" and type 'Bitmap'."

How can I fix this problem? As it seems as if the compiler is reading the code before it's taken to the file.

thanks!
Liam Hackett

```
 'Saves the map into a .TXT file
    Dim mydocpath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    'Used to manage compiler
    Dim MLN As Byte
    Dim FC As Boolean = True

    'Two "FOR" loops one for the Horizontal axis for the map and one for the Verticle axis
    For x = 1 To 10
        For y = 1 To 10

            'On first loop
            If FC = True Then
                sb.AppendLine("If WorldHorizontal = " & x & "And WorldVerticle = " & y & " Then")
                sb.AppendLine("")
                MLN = MLN + 1
                sb.AppendLine("Me.BackgroundImage = WindowsApplication1.My.Resources.Resources." & MapLayout(MLN).Image)
                sb.AppendLine("")
                FC = False

                'Everyother loop
            Else
                sb.AppendLine("ElseIf WorldHorizontal = " & x & "And WorldVerticle = " & y & " Then")
                sb.AppendLine("")
                MLN = MLN + 1
                sb.AppendLine("Me.BackgroundImage = WindowsApplication1.My.Resources.Resources." & MapLayout(MLN).Image)
                sb.AppendLine("")
            End If

        Next
    Next

    ' Saves file in MyDocuments
    Using outfile As New StreamWriter(mydocpath & "\" & txtbFileName.Text & ".txt")
        outfile.Write(sb.ToString())
    End Using
    MsgBox("Compile Finished")
```

Comment: Are you generating code?  Then it probably should be "MapLayout(" + CStr(MLN) + ").Image"

Answer (score 0):

Obviously  `MapLayout(MLN).Image` is a `Bitmap`, Bitmaps haven't overridden the `&`-operator (`+`in C#). So you cannot concatenate strings with it in this way:

```
Dim doesNotCompile = "Path of this Bitmap: " & bitmap
```

I assume that you want to concat image-path. But a Bitmap doesn't store it's path somewhere. So you must save it yourself in your class or method.